# How to get the query result into a variable and display it in labels

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

How to get the query result into a variable and display it in labels. I tried with and without `DR.Read` and `While DR.Read` and it still fails.
Here's a sample of my code

```
Public dataCNN As New MySqlConnection
Public dataCMD As New MySqlCommand
Public DR As MySqlDataReader
Public DA As MySqlDataAdapter
Public DT As DataTable
Public QUERY As String

Public Sub dbConnection()
    dataCNN = New MySqlConnection
    dataCNN.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=password;database=data"
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call dbConnection()
    txt1.Focus()
    dataCNN.Open()
    QUERY = "SELECT * FROM data.numbering WHERE id=1"
    dataCMD = New MySqlCommand(QUERY, dataCNN)
    DR = dataCMD.ExecuteReader()

    If DR.HasRows Then
        While DR.Read
            Label1.Text = DR("number").ToString()
        End While
    End If
    dataCNN.Close()
End Sub 

Private Sub txt1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txt1.KeyPress
    Dim a, b, c As Integer
    If (Val(Asc(e.KeyChar) = 33)) Then
        Label2.Text = "Teller 1 is now serving number"
        a = Label1.Text + 1

        Label1.Text = a
        DA = New MySqlDataAdapter("UPDATE data.numbering SET number='" & a & "' WHERE id=1", dataCNN)
    End If
    'MsgBox("" & Val(Asc(e.KeyChar)))
End Sub
```

Comment: *it still fails* ... post the error message? what you mean by fails?

Comment: You have to execute the command. `DR = dataCMD.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: fails i mean not working sorry for that but no errors

Comment: use DR = dataCMD.ExecuteReader() after  dataCMD = New MySqlCommand(QUERY, dataCNN). DR is not having any data so it is not working.

Comment: thanks @Crowcoder  one more thing in this query its not working i'm trying to update by 1 everytime it is keypress  `DA = New MySqlDataAdapter("UPDATE data.numbering SET num=num+1 WHERE id=1", dataCNN)`

Comment: Thanks @learningNew can you help in another problem it is post above this comment

Comment: you need to use executenonquery();

Comment: use executenonquery(); after DA = new mysqldataAdapter?

Comment: @NathanNathaniel added answer for both.

Comment: even though the above procedure  may be not vulnerable you will have to use `prepared statements` if you're actually feeding user input into SQL queries - otherwise you're creating massive, gaping security hole which enables pretty much everyone to modify and/or read your entire database. Just saying.

Comment: I' just making a queuing system it has multiple user everytime it press a set key it will add 1 to the number

Comment: thats nice ... but nobody asked for your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

You should add,

```
DR = dataCMD.ExecuteReader()
```

after

```
dataCMD = New MySqlCommand(QUERY, dataCNN)
```

EDIT: as mentioned in your comments for update you can do like this

```
Using connection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim  Mycmd As New MySqlCommand(yourquery, connection)
     Mycmd.Connection.Open()
     Mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

you need not to close the connection if you use  'using'.

Comment: Update example should use MySQL provider.

Comment: Thanks... missed it completely.

Comment: My code updated can you check why it doesn't update it by 1 it on keypress

Comment: @NathanNathaniel you can accept it as an answer if it helped.